# Creating selectbox in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create select box just like creating events in calendar when choosing start time and end time. Any suggestion?

Because I can't find any resources about this.
Please help.

Comment: Search for `UIDatePicker` and `UIPickerView`.  You can drag these out in Interface Builder and configure them.

Comment: thanks @vacawama really appreciated your helps.i got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, we handle this using `UIDatePicker` or custom of `UIPickerView`. But, it's still able to create something like a select box using `UITableView`. Some people do want it look like a select box instead of using the native iOS widget. However, we always suggest to use the iOS widget so that user will not get confused because they have adapted to the iOS world.

Answer (score 0):

Using UIPickerView solved the problem.